# converting string to integer in ansible

Tags: json, ansible, playback

In ansible i am running a role to create retention rules for some projects. using PUT method i stored results in register module, from that i am trying to read `retention_id: "59"` and `project_id: "80"` i need this as integer like `59 and 80` , but it is taking as string to the field but i need it as integer. i tried to change that by using  `"{{ item.project_id | int }}"`
and `{{ item.metadata.retention_id | int}}`

it was not changed to integer, i tried to converted the yaml body to JSON for luck. still i am getting the error.

i got struck with this task since one week . please provide any solution to get out of this.

your response will be appreciated. Thank you

### actual playbook:

```
---
# List of projects to check retention and project ID's
- name: get projects
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ ansible_host }}/api/v2.0/projects"
    method: GET
    headers:
      Authorization: "{{ admin_passwd }}"
      Accept: application/json
    validate_certs: no
  register: projects_result 
- debug:
    var: projects_result.json | flatten(levels=1)
  
# Create retention rules for the projects
- name: creating retention rules 
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ ansible_host }}/api/v2.0/retentions/{{ item.metadata.retention_id | int}}"
    method: PUT
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      Authorization: "{{ admin_passwd }}"
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*'      
    body: 
      algorithm: "or"
      id: "{{ item.metadata.retention_id | int }}"
      rules: 
      - action: "retain"
        params: 
          latestPushedK: 3
        scope_selectors:
          repository: 
          - decoration: "repoMatches"
            kind: "doublestar"
            pattern: "**"
        tag_selectors: 
        - decoration: "matches"
          extras: "{\"untagged\":true}"
          kind: "doublestar"
          pattern: "**" 
        template: latestPushedK 
      scope: 
        level: "project"
        ref: "{{ item.project_id | int }}"
      trigger: 
        kind: "Schedule"
        settings:
          cron: "0 0 * * * *"
    validate_certs: no
    status_code: 200
  when: "item.registry_id is defined"
  loop: "{{ projects_result.json | flatten(levels=1) }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

with this i was getting this error:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i ansible/inventories/shiplab ansible/playbooks/harbor-configurations.yaml --ask-vault-pass
Vault password:

PLAY [harbor] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [harbor_shiplab_test1e]

TASK [../roles/harbor-retention-rules : get projects] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [harbor_shiplab_test1e]

TASK [../roles/harbor-retention-rules : debug] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [harbor_shiplab_test1e] => {
    "projects_result.json | flatten(levels=1)": [
        {
            "chart_count": 0,
            "creation_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:28.228Z",
            "current_user_role_id": 1,
            "current_user_role_ids": [
                1
            ],
            "cve_allowlist": {
                "creation_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "id": 56,
                "items": [],
                "project_id": 75,
                "update_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "public": "true",
                "retention_id": "54"
            },
            "name": "harbor-esl-proxy",
            "owner_id": 1,
            "owner_name": "admin",
            "project_id": 75,
            "registry_id": 101,
            "repo_count": 0,
            "update_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:28.228Z"
        },
        {
            "chart_count": 0,
            "creation_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:43.098Z",
            "current_user_role_id": 1,
            "current_user_role_ids": [
                1
            ],
            "cve_allowlist": {
                "creation_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "id": 58,
                "items": [],
                "project_id": 77,
                "update_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "public": "true",
                "retention_id": "56"
            },
            "name": "harbor-library-proxy",
            "owner_id": 1,
            "owner_name": "admin",
            "project_id": 77,
            "registry_id": 103,
            "repo_count": 0,
            "update_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:43.098Z"
        },
        {
            "chart_count": 0,
            "creation_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:13.930Z",
            "current_user_role_id": 1,
            "current_user_role_ids": [
                1
            ],
            "cve_allowlist": {
                "creation_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "id": 54,
                "items": [],
                "project_id": 73,
                "update_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "public": "true",
                "retention_id": "52"
            },
            "name": "harbor-megatron-proxy",
            "owner_id": 1,
            "owner_name": "admin",
            "project_id": 73,
            "registry_id": 104,
            "repo_count": 0,
            "update_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:13.930Z"
        },
        {
            "chart_count": 0,
            "creation_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:50.271Z",
            "current_user_role_id": 1,
            "current_user_role_ids": [
                1
            ],
            "cve_allowlist": {
                "creation_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "id": 59,
                "items": [],
                "project_id": 78,
                "update_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "public": "true",
                "retention_id": "57"
            },
            "name": "harbor-migration-poc-proxy",
            "owner_id": 1,
            "owner_name": "admin",
            "project_id": 78,
            "registry_id": 105,
            "repo_count": 0,
            "update_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:50.271Z"
        },
        {
            "chart_count": 0,
            "creation_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:57.671Z",
            "current_user_role_id": 1,
            "current_user_role_ids": [
                1
            ],
            "cve_allowlist": {
                "creation_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "id": 60,
                "items": [],
                "project_id": 79,
                "update_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "public": "true",
                "retention_id": "58"
            },
            "name": "harbor-payment-proxy",
            "owner_id": 1,
            "owner_name": "admin",
            "project_id": 79,
            "registry_id": 106,
            "repo_count": 0,
            "update_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:57.671Z"
        },
        {
            "chart_count": 0,
            "creation_time": "2021-10-21T07:36:05.861Z",
            "current_user_role_id": 1,
            "current_user_role_ids": [
                1
            ],
            "cve_allowlist": {
                "creation_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "id": 61,
                "items": [],
                "project_id": 80,
                "update_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "public": "true",
                "retention_id": "59"
            },
            "name": "harbor-platform-proxy",
            "owner_id": 1,
            "owner_name": "admin",
            "project_id": 80,
            "registry_id": 107,
            "repo_count": 0,
            "update_time": "2021-10-21T07:36:05.861Z"
        },
        {
            "chart_count": 1,
            "creation_time": "2021-08-19T15:50:23.772Z",
            "current_user_role_id": 1,
            "current_user_role_ids": [
                1
            ],
            "cve_allowlist": {
                "creation_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "id": 1,
                "items": [],
                "project_id": 1,
                "update_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "public": "true"
            },
            "name": "library",
            "owner_id": 1,
            "owner_name": "admin",
            "project_id": 1,
            "repo_count": 3,
            "update_time": "2021-08-19T15:50:23.772Z"
        },
        {
            "chart_count": 2,
            "creation_time": "2021-08-24T16:45:19.230Z",
            "current_user_role_id": 1,
            "current_user_role_ids": [
                1
            ],
            "cve_allowlist": {
                "creation_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "id": 2,
                "items": [],
                "project_id": 2,
                "update_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "public": "true"
            },
            "name": "platform",
            "owner_id": 1,
            "owner_name": "admin",
            "project_id": 2,
            "repo_count": 11,
            "update_time": "2021-08-24T16:45:19.230Z"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [../roles/harbor-retention-rules : creating retention rules] *******************************************************************************************
failed: [harbor_shiplab_test1e] (item={'chart_count': 0, 'creation_time': '2021-10-21T07:35:28.228Z', 
'current_user_role_id': 1, 'current_user_role_ids': [1], 'cve_allowlist': {'creation_time': '0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', 
'id': 56, 'items': [], 'project_id': 75, 'update_time': '0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'}, 
'metadata': {'public': 'true', 'retention_id': '54'}, 'name': 'harbor-esl-proxy', 'owner_id': 1, 'owner_name': 'admin', 'project_id': 75, 
'registry_id': 101, 'repo_count': 0, 'update_time': '2021-10-21T07:35:28.228Z'}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, 
"connection": "close", "content": "{\"errors\":[{\"code\":\"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY\",\"message\":\"validation failure 
list:\\nparsing policy body from \\\"\\\" failed, because json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field RetentionPolicy.id of type int64\"}]}\n", 
"content_length": "213", "content_type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "date": "Fri, 22 Oct 2021 12:26:56 GMT", "elapsed": 1, 
"item": {"chart_count": 0, "creation_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:28.228Z", "current_user_role_id": 1, "current_user_role_ids": [1], 
"cve_allowlist": {"creation_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z", "id": 56, "items": [], "project_id": 75, "update_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}, 
"metadata": {"public": "true", "retention_id": "54"}, "name": "harbor-esl-proxy", "owner_id": 1, "owner_name": "admin", "project_id": 75, 
"registry_id": 101, "repo_count": 0, "update_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:28.228Z"}, "json": {"errors": [{"code": "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY", 
"message": "validation failure list:\nparsing policy body from \"\" failed, because json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field RetentionPolicy.id of type int64"}]}, 
"msg": "Status code was 422 and not [200]: HTTP Error 422: Unprocessable Entity", "redirected": false, "set_cookie": "sid=2e5f911867c675528b5e23c74f803240; Path=/; HttpOnly", 
"status": 422, "url": "https://harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com/api/v2.0/retentions/54", "vary": "Accept-Encoding", "x_request_id": "334cb06f-c161-4085-8df2-a448b7776819"}
```

after this i changed body to json :

### json converted:

```
- name: creating retention rules 
  uri:
    url: "https://{{ ansible_host }}/api/v2.0/retentions/{{ item.metadata.retention_id | int }}"
    method: PUT
    body_format: json
    headers:
      Content-Type: application/json
      Authorization: "{{ admin_passwd }}"
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*'      
    body: 
     '{ "algorithm": "or",
      "id": {{ item.metadata.retention_id | int }},
      "rules": [{
      "action": "retain",
        "params": {
          "latestPushedK": 3 },
        "scope_selectors":{
          "repository": [{
          "decoration": "repoMatches",
            "kind": "doublestar",
            "pattern": "**" } ] },
        "tag_selectors": [{
        "decoration": "matches",
          "extras": "{\"untagged\":true}",
          "kind": "doublestar",
          "pattern": "**" }],
        "template": latestPushedK } ],
      "scope": {
        "level": "project",
        "ref": {{ item.project_id | int }} },
      "trigger": {
        "kind": "Schedule",
        "settings":{
          "cron": "0 0 * * * *" }}}'
    validate_certs: no
    status_code: 200
  when: "item.registry_id is defined"
  loop: "{{ projects_result.json | flatten(levels=1) }}"
  ignore_errors: yes
```

with this also i am getting the same error. please help me out on this.

verbosity information:

**ansible-playbook -i ansible/inventories/shiplab ansible/playbooks/harbor-configurations.yaml --ask-vault-pass -vvv**

```
ansible-playbook -i ansible/inventories/shiplab ansible/playbooks/harbor-configurations.yaml --ask-vault-pass -vvv
ansible-playbook 2.8.4
  config file = /home/user1/repos/harbor/konvoy/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/user1/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.7.10 (default, May  5 2021, 11:43:58) [GCC 10.2.0]
Using /home/user1/repos/harbor/konvoy/ansible.cfg as config file
Vault password:
host_list declined parsing /home/user1/repos/harbor/konvoy/ansible/inventories/shiplab/test1e as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/user1/repos/harbor/konvoy/ansible/inventories/shiplab/test1e as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
Parsed /home/user1/repos/harbor/konvoy/ansible/inventories/shiplab/test1e inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: harbor-configurations.yaml ************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in ansible/playbooks/harbor-configurations.yaml

PLAY [harbor] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/user1/repos/harbor/konvoy/ansible/playbooks/harbor-configurations.yaml:2
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: MEA+user1
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo '"'"'~MEA+user1'"'"' && sleep 0'
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~MEA+user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916091.044559-272844769197129 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1634916091.044559-272844769197129="` echo ~MEA+user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916091.044559-272844769197129 `" ) && sleep 0'
<harbor_shiplab_test1e> Attempting python interpreter discovery
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo PLATFORM; uname; echo FOUND; command -v '"'"'/usr/bin/python'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.7'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.6'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python3.5'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python2.7'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python2.6'"'"'; command -v '"'"'/usr/libexec/platform-python'"'"'; command -v '"'"'/usr/bin/python3'"'"'; command -v '"'"'python'"'"'; echo ENDFOUND && sleep 0'
<harbor_shiplab_test1e> Python interpreter discovery fallback (unsupported platform for extended discovery: cygwin_nt-10.0)
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/system/setup.py
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> PUT /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1736l28mza02/tmp5ucaxth_ TO /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916091.044559-272844769197129/AnsiballZ_setup.py
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916091.044559-272844769197129/ /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916091.044559-272844769197129/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916091.044559-272844769197129/AnsiballZ_setup.py && sleep 0'
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916091.044559-272844769197129/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [harbor_shiplab_test1e]
META: ran handlers

TASK [../roles/harbor-retention-rules : get projects] *******************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/user1/repos/harbor/konvoy/ansible/roles/harbor-retention-rules/tasks/main.yml:3
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: MEA+user1
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo '"'"'~MEA+user1'"'"' && sleep 0'
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~MEA+user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916112.1313658-277975019551630 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1634916112.1313658-277975019551630="` echo ~MEA+user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916112.1313658-277975019551630 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/net_tools/basics/uri.py
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> PUT /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1736l28mza02/tmpsm6sxu8_ TO /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916112.1313658-277975019551630/AnsiballZ_uri.py
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916112.1313658-277975019551630/ /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916112.1313658-277975019551630/AnsiballZ_uri.py && sleep 0'
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916112.1313658-277975019551630/AnsiballZ_uri.py && sleep 0'
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916112.1313658-277975019551630/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
ok: [harbor_shiplab_test1e] => {
    "changed": false,
    "connection": "close",
    "content_type": "application/json",
    "cookies": {
        "sid": "033af4ae913d69a8314a4edb84512aa6"
    },
    "cookies_string": "sid=033af4ae913d69a8314a4edb84512aa6",
    "date": "Fri, 22 Oct 2021 15:22:01 GMT",
    "elapsed": 1,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": null,
            "body": null,
            "body_format": "raw",
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "content": null,
            "creates": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "dest": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "follow": false,
            "follow_redirects": "safe",
            "force": false,
            "force_basic_auth": false,
            "group": null,
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46SGFyYm9yMTIzNDU="
            },
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "method": "GET",
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "regexp": null,
            "remote_src": null,
            "removes": null,
            "return_content": false,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "status_code": [
                200
            ],
            "timeout": 30,
            "unix_socket": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "url": "https://harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com/api/v2.0/projects",
            "url_password": null,
            "url_username": null,
            "use_proxy": true,
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "json": [
        {
            "chart_count": 0,
            "creation_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:28.228Z",
            "current_user_role_id": 1,
            "current_user_role_ids": [
                1
            ],
            "cve_allowlist": {
                "creation_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
                "id": 56,
                "items": [],
                "project_id": 75,
                "update_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "public": "true",
                "retention_id": "54"
            },
            "name": "harbor-esl-proxy",
            "owner_id": 1,
            "owner_name": "admin",
            "project_id": 75,
            "registry_id": 101,
            "repo_count": 0,
            "update_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:28.228Z"
        }
            ],
    "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)",
    "redirected": false,
    "set_cookie": "sid=033af4ae913d69a8314a4edb84512aa6; Path=/; HttpOnly",
    "status": 200,
    "transfer_encoding": "chunked",
    "url": "https://harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com/api/v2.0/projects",
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "x_request_id": "c1d907c3-e324-49a5-a582-82f9672d1f8d",
    "x_total_count": "8"
}


TASK [../roles/harbor-retention-rules : creating retention rules] *******************************************************************************************
task path: /home/user1/repos/harbor/konvoy/ansible/roles/harbor-retention-rules/tasks/main.yml:36
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: MEA+user1
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo '"'"'~MEA+user1'"'"' && sleep 0'
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo ~MEA+user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916125.1009495-142461137289702 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1634916125.1009495-142461137289702="` echo ~MEA+user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916125.1009495-142461137289702 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/net_tools/basics/uri.py
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> PUT /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1736l28mza02/tmpy38u0lww TO /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916125.1009495-142461137289702/AnsiballZ_uri.py
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916125.1009495-142461137289702/ /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916125.1009495-142461137289702/AnsiballZ_uri.py && sleep 0'
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916125.1009495-142461137289702/AnsiballZ_uri.py && sleep 0'
<harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1634916125.1009495-142461137289702/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
failed: [harbor_shiplab_test1e] (item={'chart_count': 0, 'creation_time': '2021-10-21T07:35:28.228Z', 'current_user_role_id': 1, 'current_user_role_ids': [1], 'cve_allowlist': {'creation_time': '0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'id': 56, 'items': [], 'project_id': 75, 'update_time': '0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'}, 'metadata': {'public': 'true', 'retention_id': '54'}, 'name': 'harbor-esl-proxy', 'owner_id': 1, 'owner_name': 'admin', 'project_id': 75, 'registry_id': 101, 'repo_count': 0, 'update_time': '2021-10-21T07:35:28.228Z'}) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "connection": "close",
    "content": "{\"errors\":[{\"code\":\"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY\",\"message\":\"validation failure list:\\nparsing policy body from \\\"\\\" failed, because json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field RetentionPolicy.id of type int64\"}]}\n",
    "content_length": "213",
    "content_type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "date": "Fri, 22 Oct 2021 15:22:17 GMT",
    "elapsed": 3,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": null,
            "body": {
                "algorithm": "or",
                "id": "54",
                "rules": [
                    {
                        "action": "retain",
                        "params": {
                            "latestPushedK": 3
                        },
                        "scope_selectors": {
                            "repository": [
                                {
                                    "decoration": "repoMatches",
                                    "kind": "doublestar",
                                    "pattern": "**"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "tag_selectors": [
                            {
                                "decoration": "matches",
                                "extras": "{\"untagged\":true}",
                                "kind": "doublestar",
                                "pattern": "**"
                            }
                        ],
                        "template": "latestPushedK"
                    }
                ],
                "scope": {
                    "level": "project",
                    "ref": "75"
                },
                "trigger": {
                    "kind": "Schedule",
                    "settings": {
                        "cron": "0 0 * * * *"
                    }
                }
            },
            "body_format": "json",
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "content": null,
            "creates": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "dest": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "follow": false,
            "follow_redirects": "safe",
            "force": false,
            "force_basic_auth": false,
            "group": null,
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "Authorization": "Basic YWRtaW46SGFyYm9yMTIzNDU=",
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
            "method": "PUT",
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "regexp": null,
            "remote_src": null,
            "removes": null,
            "return_content": false,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": null,
            "status_code": [
                "200"
            ],
            "timeout": 30,
            "unix_socket": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null,
            "url": "https://harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com/api/v2.0/retentions/54",
            "url_password": null,
            "url_username": null,
            "use_proxy": true,
            "validate_certs": false
        }
    },
    "item": {
        "chart_count": 0,
        "creation_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:28.228Z",
        "current_user_role_id": 1,
        "current_user_role_ids": [
            1
        ],
        "cve_allowlist": {
            "creation_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "id": 56,
            "items": [],
            "project_id": 75,
            "update_time": "0001-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        "metadata": {
            "public": "true",
            "retention_id": "54"
        },
        "name": "harbor-esl-proxy",
        "owner_id": 1,
        "owner_name": "admin",
        "project_id": 75,
        "registry_id": 101,
        "repo_count": 0,
        "update_time": "2021-10-21T07:35:28.228Z"
    },
    "json": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "code": "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
                "message": "validation failure list:\nparsing policy body from \"\" failed, because json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field RetentionPolicy.id of type int64"
            }
        ]
    },
    "msg": "Status code was 422 and not [200]: HTTP Error 422: Unprocessable Entity",
    "redirected": false,
    "set_cookie": "sid=5ffe84980b5cb188e7821ae838e4fc33; Path=/; HttpOnly",
    "status": 422,
    "url": "https://harbor.tst1e.k8s.shiplab.ss.acl.com/api/v2.0/retentions/54",
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "x_request_id": "d7a855cf-3de6-47ab-8b47-d275cda5274b"
}
   "skip_reason": "Conditional result was False"
}
...ignoring
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
harbor_shiplab_test1e      : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

Comment: Why does that task have `ignore_errors: yes`? And have you tried increasing the verbosity of that playbook to see the actual payload it is sending? We'd actually be able to help you more if you distilled your problem down into an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i am running a playbook with multiple tasks, to keep playbook running to the end i used ```ignore_errors: yes```  and i copied the verbosity of the playbook above. please have a look. i copied one set of the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, what a fascinating rabbit hole :-(

So, there is [an existing issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/59732#issuecomment-791484225) reporting that behavior, but it was closed "works-as-designed," along with some nonsense about configuring jinja2 in some incompatible way

As best I can tell from running a *bunch* of experiments, manually crafting that JSON payload is the only safe way:

```yaml
      body_format: json
      body: >-
        {{ 
         (
          {
            "algorithm": "or",
            "id": item.metadata.retention_id | int,
            "rules": [
              {
                "action": "retain",
                "params": {
                  "latestPushedK": 3
                },
                "scope_selectors": {
                  "repository": [
                    {
                      "decoration": "repoMatches",
                      "kind": "doublestar",
                      "pattern": "**"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "tag_selectors": [
                  {
                    "decoration": "matches",
                    "kind": "doublestar",
                    "pattern": "**"
                  }
                ],
                "template": "latestPushedK"
              }
            ],
            "scope": {
              "level": "project",
              "ref": item.project_id | int
            },
            "trigger": {
              "kind": "Schedule",
              "settings": {
                "cron": "0 0 * * * *"
              }
            }
          }
          ) | to_json }}
    when: "item.registry_id is defined"
```

I wish I had a better *explanation* as to what is going on, but given the response to that issue, I'm not super sure they even consider your experience to be a bug

But for clarity, what is happening here is that those leading brace characters inside the `()` are *python dict* literals, which is why the `"id": item.metadata.retention_id | int,` doesn't need any special consideration -- both sides of that are python (err, jinja2, but same-same)

The `()` are likely not strictly necessary, but do make it super obvious what is being fed into the `| to_json` filter

Then, the outer `{{` are the jinja2 delimiters that you're used to, in order to have all that inner jinja2 code run, and the `body: >-` is to get us out of yaml quoting hell

Comment: You are really awesome @mdaniel, Thank you very much for your help. i amazed on your work

Comment: You're very kind to say that, and I'm glad it worked for you. I'm sorry you had that experience, and I still wish I understood why jinja2 behaved that way across every other attempt I made to fix it

Comment: Thank you @mdaniel, this has solved my never-ending ansible mystery on how to correctly work with original json body... thanks!